# aws keeps re-Provisioning if task fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We have fargate setup and we set essential=true. When we deploy to aws ecs instance, the task fails after couple of minutes. You can see aws trying to provision a new one. This happens every 5 mintues.

How do I stop aws fargate from provision new task and let task be in failed state?

Comment: we set essential=false and builds stopped working

Comment: Is this an ECS service?

Comment: yes it is. Right now we are just manually killing service as we see them, but its costing a lot.

Comment: You could enable ECS Circuit Breaker so that it will eventually stop trying to deploy your failing task: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/deployment-circuit-breaker.html However by using a Service instead of a simpler ECS task, you are inherently telling AWS you want this service to be running 24/7. Is that not what you actually want? Please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: I am completely from dev side and infra is a new to me. Can you tell me what kind of information you would need?

Comment: Let's start with the question I already asked. Do you need the task running all the time (24/7/365) or do you only need it to only run at certain times, like on a schedule, or in response to an event or something?